# Wrong RAM values in indicator-multiload popup

Tags: 16.04, indicator, ram, indicator-multiload

The RAM (memory) values presented in indicator popup does not match with the same values in Gnome System Monitor (let's abbreviate it as SM).

For example, about memory used, **SM shows 7.0 GiB and indicator shows 7.5GB.**
The same occurs in total / physical memory, my system has 8 GB of RAM, Ubuntu recognizes about ~7.7 GB and SM represents correctly this value, "free" command too... but indicator shows 8.3 MB. Totally confusing.

Other values (disk, CPU, etc.) seems to be legit.

Ubuntu 16.04.1 64bits

Thanks!!

Comment: Hopefully this calculator can help explain the differences:  http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GiB differs from GB. 1 GiB is 1,073,741,824 bytes. 1 GB is 1,000,000,000 bytes.

7 GiB is 7,516,192,768 bytes, which is about 7.5 GB.

Comment: Yeah, finally I understand the difference between both, indicator-multiload is using GB instead of GiB which is more comprehensible for me.  Thanks!